# ion_auth disable post method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using [ion_auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/)  library to my project (for the first time).

now, my post methods not works :

my login form is :

http://www.khabgahfeiz.ir/admin/login

in my controller :

```
    public function handling() {

        var_dump($_POST['email']); // or echo $this->input->post('email'); 
        return;
....
```

but it returns `null` value and I got this error :

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: email

Filename: backend/login.php

Line Number: 29
```

I added before :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form','security','date','cookie','download');
```

my htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php53 php53 php


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^khabgahfeiz.ir$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.khabgahfeiz.ir/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>

order allow,deny
allow from all
```

Comment: Does input field have `name='email'`?

Comment: @Tpojka  yes:http://www.khabgahfeiz.ir/admin/login

Comment: Put `exit;` instead of `return;` for debugging purpose.

Comment: Also put `if ( $_POST ) { var_dump( $_POST ); exit; }`

Comment: My code : `if ( $_POST ) { var_dump( $_POST ); exit; }else {echo 'false'; return ;}`;               => it returns false ;

Comment: updated my question . my htaccess is correct?

Comment: You didn't have post array set at all. Is solved with changing base url value?

Answer (score 0):

I changed it

```
 $config['base_url']    = 'http://khabgahfeiz.ir/';
```

to :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.khabgahfeiz.ir/';
```